# Google map GMSCameraUpdate zoom minimize in swift 5

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have used `GMSCoordinateBounds`. But it zooms in too much. My marker doesn't show on the road because of the zoom level. My marker shows a little bit away from the road. I have used the below code:

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.740424444444443, 90.41102222222223))
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
self.googleMap.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding:10.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solve the problem like bellow

```
  let path = GMSMutablePath()
  path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.740424444444443, 90.41102222222223))
  let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
  self.googleMap.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds))
  self.googleMap.setMinZoom(8, maxZoom: 14)
```